# How to prohibit modifications to all files in a revision control system

Tags: svn, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, repository-design

For an archive of test data I need a revision control system that allows only the addition of files. Modifications, renaming and any other changes are prohibited.

This will make it possible to test any code revision with the current test data and reproduce the same results as before.

We are currently using Subversion for source code. However, the test data will probably be several hundred files with about 200 GBytes of data. I doubt that Subversion can handle it. I don't want to put the test data into the same Subversion archive as the code, which only has several MBytes.

Also, Subversion doesn't seem to be the right tool for such a simple problem.

How do I create a directory in my subversion repository with an add-only rule?

I noticed, that after checkout the test data doubled in size, because there is a .svn-directory with copies of every file. Can I avoid this waste of hard disk space? Someone, who only wants to use the data but doesn't want to add anything wouldn't need it. He could just delete .svn but would still need a lot of disk space at checkout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subversion is the right tool for such case and there should be no problems handling 200GB of data or event multi TBytes of data. Note that you haven't really stated any "problem" in the question except "how to prohibit modifications", so it's not really clear what problems you ask about.

To prohibit modifications but allow additions (I don't really understand why you ask about this, just because you use a fully-fledged and feature complete version control that will control the modifications itself), use [path-based authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) and combine it with a [pre-commit hook script](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html). Write the hook script yourself or use [`svnperms`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/) hook script written in Python.

And don't forget to read the documentation: [SVNBook 1.8](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/).

Comment: I tested svn by creating a repository with 18G of test data.  The repository obviously detects duplicate data and has only 11G. If I do a checkout, I get 36G because the tree contains a .svn directory with copies of all files.
du -hs *
18G     original-test-data/11G     repository/
36G     test-data-after-checkout/

Comment: @MarkusHeitz in such case run `svn export` as @ojblass suggested.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the second part of your question you can do an svn export to only get one copy of your data.  You will not be able to commit to that folder because it is not a working copy.  I have a repository that is well over 200 GB.  No problems so far.